# Convert nested dictionary to appended dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary as such:

```
{1:{'name':'john', 'age':26,'salary':50000},11:{'name':'peter', 'age':34, 'salary':70000},14:{'name': 'david', 'age': 21, 'salary': 15000}}
```

I would like to convert it to a dataframe like this:

```
name  age  salary
john  26   50000
peter 34   70000
david 21   15000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `from_dict` with `orient='index'`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

```
     name  age  salary
1    john   26   50000
11  peter   34   70000
14  david   21   15000
```

Comment: Can I create a column name for the indexes(1,11,14) in the above dataframe and create a seperate serialized index

Comment: Yes, just call `reset_index` on the result

Answer (score 2):

You can load the dictionary directly into a dataframe and then transpose it:

```
d = {1:{'name':'john', 'age':26,'salary':50000},11:{'name':'peter', 'age':34, 'salary':70000},14:{'name': 'david', 'age': 21, 'salary': 15000}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

   age   name salary
1   26   john  50000
11  34  peter  70000
14  21  david  15000
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct the dataframe out of your dict's values.

```
>>> d = {1:{'name':'john', 'age':26,'salary':50000},11:{'name':'peter', 'age':34, 'salary':70000},14:{'name': 'david', 'age': 21, 'salary': 15000}}
>>> pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()))
   age   name  salary
0   26   john   50000
1   34  peter   70000
2   21  david   15000
```

With rearranged columns:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()), columns=['name', 'age', 'salary'])
    name  age  salary
0   john   26   50000
1  peter   34   70000
2  david   21   15000
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()))
```

If you're using Python2, you can directly call pd.DataFrame with `p.values()` like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(d.values())
```

This is because dictionary values no longer returns a list in python3